# Pesquisar somente arquivos criados por mim no Google Drive

Tags: javascript, script, google-drive-api

Bom dia

Estou criando um script para deletar arquivos com mais de 3 horas de criação em uma pasta no Google Drive, mas existe um certo bloqueio que você só pode deletar arquivos criados por você, então preciso que o script pesquise somente esses arquivos criados por mim especificamente

```
var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');
```

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda, em como eu poderia ajustar essa linha de script (logo acima) para que ele pesquise a data de modificação do arquivo e também filtre somente os arquivos que foram criados por mim

Caso ajude mais, este é o script completo:

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  // Old date is 3 Hours
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
  var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  obj.sort(function(x, y) {return x.date < y.date ? 1 : -1});
  obj.shift();
  var fileIDs = obj.map(function(e) {return e.id});
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    Drive.Files.remove(fileID);
  });
};
```

Comment: na query ali em searchfiles é só por um " and 'voce@mail.com' in owners "

Comment: `var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '" and 'voce@mail.com' in owners ');`

Ficaria dessa forma @LucasMiranda ?